# (R ggplot2) Remove grid lines and spacing between panel border and axis text or ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is an example plot:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(x=c(0,100), y=c(1,0)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_segment(x=0, y=0, xend=0, yend=1.1, color="gray60", size=0.6, lineend="square") +
  geom_segment(x=0, y=0, xend=110, yend=0, color="gray60", size=0.6, lineend="square") +
  geom_line(color="#66ccff", size=3, lineend = "round") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(y="Y Label", x="X Label") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,100,by=20), minor_breaks=NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, minor_breaks=NULL) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16, color="gray30"),
        axis.text = element_text(size=14, color="gray30"))
```

[image]
I want to eliminate the grid outside the limits of the data. This (less ideal, imo) hack with the rectangles covers up the grid lines outside of the panel border:

```
tibble(x=c(0,100), y=c(1,0)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_line(color="#66ccff", size=3, lineend = "round") +
  geom_segment(x=0, y=0, xend=0, yend=1.1, color="gray60", size=0.6, lineend="square") +
  geom_segment(x=0, y=0, xend=110, yend=0, color="gray60", size=0.6, lineend="square") +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_rect(xmin=-5, xmax=0, ymin=-4, ymax=1.1, fill="white") +
  geom_rect(xmin=-5, xmax=110, ymin=-4, ymax=0, fill="white") +
  labs(y="Y Label", x="X Label") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,100,by=20), minor_breaks=NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, minor_breaks=NULL) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16, color="gray30"),
        axis.text = element_text(size=14, color="gray30"))
```

[image]
But I really want a way to eliminate/reduce that space, so that it looks more like this:
[image]
I very often find people who want plots to look like this.
How could I do that?

Comment: This can be accomplished by adding e.g., vjust and hjust to: axis.text.x = element_text(...) and axis.text.y = element_text(...).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well, what you want is to remove the ticks that point to each of the values in the X and Y axis. If that is the case, you can try with :

```
tibble(x=c(0,100), y=c(1,0)) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
        geom_segment(x=0, y=0, xend=0, yend=1.1, color="gray60", size=0.6, lineend="square") +
        geom_segment(x=0, y=0, xend=110, yend=0, color="gray60", size=0.6, lineend="square") +
        geom_line(color="#66ccff", size=3, lineend = "round") +
        theme_minimal() +
        labs(y="Y Label", x="X Label") +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,100,by=20), minor_breaks=NULL) +
        scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, minor_breaks=NULL) +
        theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16, color="gray30"),
              axis.text = element_text(size=14, color="gray30"),
              axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

The only modification to your original code was the `axis.ticks = element_blank()`

---

**EDIT:** It seems (from the image with your desired output) that you also want to make the axis to be more close to the panel of your plot. If that's the case, you can try to add `expand = c(0,0)` to both `scale_x_continuos` and `scale_y_continuos` functions. If that's true, your code should look like this:

```
tibble(x=c(0,100), y=c(1,0)) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
        geom_segment(x=0, y=0, xend=0, yend=1.1, color="gray60", size=0.6, lineend="square") +
        geom_segment(x=0, y=0, xend=110, yend=0, color="gray60", size=0.6, lineend="square") +
        geom_line(color="#66ccff", size=3, lineend = "round") +
        theme_minimal() +
        labs(y="Y Label", x="X Label") +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,100,by=20), minor_breaks=NULL, expand = c(0,0)) +
        scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, minor_breaks=NULL, expand = c(0,0)) +
        theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16, color="gray30"),
              axis.text = element_text(size=14, color="gray30"),
              axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

Comment: I think theme_minimal already doesn't use ticks. `expand = c(0.01,0.01)` is about right for my case. Not sure how to expand in a different amount each way though.
vjust also quite useful.

Comment: You can use expand in each `scale_` function (i.e, for each axis). Then, each element inside the vector you give to the `expand` argument refers to one of the edges of each axis, so now you can change the expand for each edge of each axis at will. Nice that my code was useful for you! If that's the case, please consider to accept the answer (clicking the tick). It would make easier for other people with the same problem to find an answer/to see that it works

Comment: I assumed that the values are start and stop, but for some reason they don't work correctly. I don't have time to troubleshoot it more though.